# How to recursively find the index of a max element in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, max

It doesn't seem too hard to get the max value:

```
int getMax(int arr[], int size) {
    if(size == 1) {
        return arr[0]
    }
    return max(arr[size - 1], getMaxIndex(arr, size - 1));
}
```

But how can I find the index of where it was at? If I create a count variable it will just get wiped as soon I recursively call. I can't find anywhere online where someone does this recursively with only the array and a size parameter. Thanks for any help.

Comment: That function is called `getMaxIndex`, when it just gets the largest number. Perhaps name it `getMax`

Comment: Sorry I got confused with the function that I wanted to code.

Comment: I understand this might be an exercise, but in case you are unaware, doing this recursively is needlessly problematic.

Comment: ...and also uses a horrific O(n) memory to solve something a simple for loop does.

Comment: Would it be cheating to find the max value, then loop through the array and pick out the max value's position?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might do it like that:

```
int getMaxIndex(int arr[], int size) {
    if (size == 1) {
        return 0;
    }
    const auto recMaxIndex = getMaxIndex(arr, size - 1);
    if (arr[recMaxIndex] < arr[size - 1]) {
        return size - 1;
    } else {
        return recMaxIndex;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by the use of writing one extra character to write auto.

Comment: @NicholasPipitone It's actually pretty smart because now all the types are defined in the first line. If you change the argument/return type, `auto` guarantees no accidental conversion can happen by forgetting to update that line.